# mouseover css menu overlap with user input text

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, tiles

From snapshot, the grey block is the mouse over dropdown menu. What's behind it is a user input on the page.

The issue is, if the input dom is not empty, meaning user has type in something and may covered by that css menu, then there is an overlap. it is only happen on IE7.

So why and how can we resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Unfortenately you can't fix this, it's a bug in IE7 and earlier IE versions. It has something to do with "Windowed" `select` implementation in older IEs.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you that's sad but very helpful information. Could you please be more specific about what's the name of this bug so I can do more search? I wonder if it is possible to do some change to the input box or drop down menu to work around this situation.

Comment: It was [KB177378](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=http://support.microsoft.com:80/support/kb/articles/q177/3/78.asp&NoWebContent=1). Also it seems that [something](http://www.macridesweb.com/oltest/IframeShim.html) can be done, looks quite hacky, but if you want to try... Though these articles seems to handle rather IE5 - IE5.5 than IE7.

Comment: @Teemu Wow, that's a quick feedback and thanks again. I will go through that tickets and article and may be will ask you more questions. Thanks to the nice mechanical engineer who is also javascript expert from Finland.

Comment: Thanks : ). I just googled for "internet explorer7 windowed select element", you can probably find more and better results, my english maybe is not good enough to filter all that stuff coming up.

Comment: @Teemu I just find this link http://tramitanet.sciebem.com.mx/javascript/datepicker/ and the widget seems works fine with the drop down box beneath in IE7... not sure it is the same situation...