# Dojo: how to find css definition for digit.form.filteringselect, especially the drop down list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dojo

we are using `tundra` theme. Getting a hard time to find style sheet definition to `digit.form.filteringselect`, especially to that drop down list area and selected text style[image]

### UPDATE

Can anyone tells me what css class in charge of the dropdown menu stylesheet? I need to know because I think this drop down menu can overcome the IE7 z-index issue, I have this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284110/mouseover-css-menu-overlap-with-user-input-text) to describe previous issue and believe knowing how this dojo component rendered may help me find a clue to fix that issue. Thanks.

Comment: this needs more detail

Comment: @Matthew Graves What else information can I provide? Isn't above enough for the question?

Comment: maybe include a sample of the html so that we can see the classes and the element's children, what you've tried already, etc.

Comment: @Matthew Graves Thanks but do you realize `Dojo` render the component by its own javascript lib and css style sheet, not by my codes, and that's the coding I am looking for? Sir do you really know anything about `filteringselect` and then just vote down my question?

Comment: You can use a DOM inspector to view the dojo output to see exactly what selectors are likely being used to style it and then use that as your guide for searching the theme's files.... Hence, some more detail would be useful.

Comment: I may be reading this wrong, but the question is very localized and perhaps a bit too "Help me google this"-like. I voted it down in hope that the author will 1) research this further and 2) try to generalize the question, including relevant HTML, CSS and JS.

Comment: I really want to find out which class take care of the drop down menu of that filteringSelect diji components...may be who works on Dojo can know what I mean.

Comment: I have updated the post, still no sample codes but additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use firefox or chrome, use the built-in console to find out. Generally all it takes is right-click an element and choose the option "Inspect Element" (or "Inspect element with firebug" if you have firebug installed).

You can do that for example by going to http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/form/_autoComplete.html?testWidget=dijit.form.FilteringSelect and right clicking on the item you want to spy on, then click "Inspect Element"

The items you mention are controlled by the following classes :

- for the text in the textbox : .tundra .dijitTextBox .dijitInputInner, .tundra .dijitTextBox .dijitInputInner
- for an option of the drop-down menu : .claro .dijitMenu .dijitMenuItem td, .claro .dijitComboBoxMenu .dijitMenuItem

However, these are generic classes used all over the place, so you DON'T want to override them in the theme directly. Instead, go through the theming tutorial at http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/themes_buttons_textboxes/, as there are many things to know about theming.

You should also read the documentation of CssStateMixin at http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/_CssStateMixin.html, in order to understand the classes dojo adds to widgets when you mouseover them, etc...

Good luck !